# Sitecore (Web Forms for Marketers) success page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

Let's imagine I've made a simple form using the Web Forms for Marketers module 2.2 (for CMS 6.4), and have set this up to use a 'success page' (server side redirect to a specified sitecore item). This works great.

Now it turns out that the thank you page needs to show certain field variables from the form which was just submitted.

> "Dear x, thank you for your interest in Y".

On the success page, it seems like there is no way to retrieve the information (server-side) I need to show this information.

What would be a good way to approach this problem?
Is there a way to hook into sitecore webforms before the page is redirected to the success page (so I can pass along an orderId, for example)?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom action which will give you access to all the forms data. From the action you can redirect the user to the appropriate place. You can find documentation on how to create a custom action in the [reference guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_2%20reference-a4.pdf) on page 42.

Make sure your action is always after Save To Database because otherwise the data won't be saved.